# Who are these people in the Kuzu no Honkai drama CDs?

Tags: kuzu-no-honkai

The first track on the [first drama CD](http://vgmdb.net/album/64673) for *Kuzu no Honkai* is titled "Nyan Nyan Prelude". It features characters named "Checo"(?) and "Shuu", the former of whom might or might not literally be a cat.

To summarize: the track begins with them doing lewd things (as is *Kuzu no Honkai*'s wont). Checo says she'll get a job, but Shuu says she can't, because she's a cat. Shuu forgets her birthday, and they get into a fight. They reminisce about the days when their relationship was all sunshine and roses. At the end of the track, they reconcile.

I don't know who these characters are. Nothing in this track (nor the next one, "Nyan Nyan Serenade") has anything to do with any of the characters or events featured in the anime, even though the narrative "feels" like that of *Kuzu no Honkai*. I'm thoroughly confused. Who are these people, and what does any of this have to do with *Kuzu no Honkai*?

Comment: isn't there any meta info around these drama CDs like a credits image or text file or text on the back of the disc case? And what about database sites like MAL, isn't there an entry for these drama cds to see the cast and who voiced which characters?

Comment: @Hakase As far as I'm aware, there are not any useful online databases for anime-related drama CDs (MAL certainly is of no use here). The closest I'm aware of is VGMdb, which will typically not have more than metadata (track names, album info, etc).

Comment: I just remembered that some versions have seiyuu's names in the audio file metadata. Check your mp3 tags to see if it contains anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen neither the *Kuzu no Honkai* anime nor the drama CD's, so I'm basing this answer on my recollection of the manga. The manga features a bunch of extras involving cats or cat-like people. (The last paragraph in [this review](https://daiyamanga.com/2015/10/08/manga-review-scums-wish/) verifies my shaky memory of the manga.) None of these have anything to do at all with the main story. [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/manga/44929/Kuzu_no_Honkai/moreinfo) gives the titles as being *Nyan Nyan $foo*, $foo being a musical form, which roughly matches my memory, so it seems likely the drama CD tracks are related to the extras.

In particular, your description of the drama CD track matches the story in the "Nyan Nyan Prelude" extra, which is after ch. 5 in vol. 1. In the manga extra, there is a human named Shu and a cat (or cat-person, I am unsure) named Chako. They have a physical relationship, but later, tensions between the two emerge. As in the drama CD, Chako speaks of getting a job, but Shu says she cannot since she is a cat, and Shu forgets Chako's birthday. Later, Shu apologises, but Chako is already convinced that:

> Because Shu-chan is so forgetful, he's already forgotten about me.